# SharePoint Apps : Who can see it in "Site contents"?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, provisioning

[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/Create-SharePoint-fields-and-content-types-based-on-element-XML-in-Apps-for-SharePoint-Office-365-De) is a good sample project that explains how to use APPS to provision custom components on sites in SharePoint online with custom fields, content types etc. In brief, the app explained in the video has a Page with a couple of Buttons on it. On click of these buttons, components like Content type or Site columns or any other custom component like master page/page layout can be provisioned on the HOST web using client object model.

Ideally this provisioning is done only once when a site is created or custom components are modified and this APP should be primarily used by the site collection administrator.

In the "Site Contents", the APP will be shown to all the users. Even if the user might not have appropriate permission to provision these components, any user might be still able to go into the app and see what's in there..if i am not wrong. !! So my question is, is there any way to control who can SEE the app in the site ?

Off course we can hide it through jquery..but is there any better way to control this ? Any thoughts.

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark, but maybe editing permissions for the app web will work.  If a user does not have access, perhaps SharePoint will trim it out of site contents for the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide list in SPDesigner. Open Site; click on list&library; right click on that list and in properties click "Hide from browser"

[image: hide it]

---

EDIT

This was for list & library

For APPS

Here is link [Learn why apps cannot be hidden from users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383%28v=office.15%29.aspx#CannotBeHidden)

Comment: The question refers to an app, not a list/library.

Comment: Sorry about that.